# Getting the count of items under diagonal in numpy

Tags: numpy, mean, diagonal

I have a correlation matrix, and I want to get the count of number of items below the diagonal. Preferably in numpy.

```
[[1,   0,   0,   0,  0], 
[.35,  1,   0,   0,  0], 
[.42, .31,  1,   0,  0], 
[.25, .38, .41,  1,  0], 
[.21, .36, .46, .31, 1]]
```

I want it to return 10. Or, to return the mean of all numbers under the diagonal.

Comment: Can you check for **numpy.trace** and letme know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***

```
a = np.array([[1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
              [0.35, 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
              [0.42, 0.31, 1.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
              [0.25, 0.38, 0.41, 1.  , 0.  ],
              [0.21, 0.36, 0.46, 0.31, 1.  ]])
```

---

[`numpy.tril_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) will give the indices of all elements under the diagonal (if you provide an offset of `-1`), and from there, it becomes as simple as indexing and calling `mean` and `size`

---

```
n, m = a.shape

m = np.tril_indices(n=n, k=-1, m=m)

a[m]
# array([0.35, 0.42, 0.31, 0.25, 0.38, 0.41, 0.21, 0.36, 0.46, 0.31])

a[m].mean()
# 0.346

a[m].size
# 10
```

Answer (score 2):

A more primitive and bulky answer since `numpy` provides `np.tril_indices` as user3483203 mentioned, but what you want per row iteration i is the following (in terms of [row,col] indices):

```
                      (i=0)
[1,0]                 (i=1) 
[2,0] [2,1]           (i=2)
[3,0] [3,1] [3,2]     (i=3)
...
```

This is essentially the `zip` of list `[i,i,i,...] = [i]*i` (i repetitions of i) with `[0,1,...,i-1] = range(i)`. So iterating over the rows of the table, you can actually get the indices per iteration and perform the operator of your choice.

Example setup:

```
test = np.array(
[[1,   0,   0,   0,  0], 
[.35,  1,   0,   0,  0], 
[.42, .31,  1,   0,  0], 
[.25, .38, .41,  1,  0], 
[.21, .36, .46, .31, 1]])
```

Function definition:

```
def countdiag(myarray):
    numvals = 0
    totsum = 0


    for i in range(myarray.shape[0]): # row iteration
        colc = np.array(range(i)) # calculate column indices
        rowc = np.array([i]*i) # calculate row indices

        if any(rowc):
            print(np.sum(myarray[rowc,colc]))
            print(len(myarray[rowc,colc]))

            numvals += len(myarray[rowc,colc])
            totsum += np.sum(myarray[rowc,colc])


        print(list(zip([i]*i, np.arange(i))))

    mean = totsum / numvals

    return mean, numvals
```

Test:

```
 [165]: countdiag(test)



[]
0.35
1
[(1, 0)]
0.73
2
[(2, 0), (2, 1)]
1.04
3
[(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
1.34
4
[(4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
0.346
Out[165]:
(0.346, 10)
```